# PPCG's Unanswered Questions

Tags: code-golf, internet, stack-exchange-api

This dear StackExchange site has so many challenges, and so many good answers. But what about the challenges that were [never answered](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/unanswered)?

### Task

Write a program or a function that will print a pseudo-random open unanswered (as in, a question with exactly zero answers) challenge from PPCG. All possible challenges should be produced with the same probability.

### Input

- No input will be taken.

### Output

- Must only be the title, tags and the link which should be separated by newlines.

  - The title must be exactly like it is in the challenge.
  - The tags don't have a strict output format but must include all tags.
  - The link may or may not include the `question-name` after the question id and must lead to the challenge.
- May or may not be translated to a human readable format.

  - `&amp;` to `&`
- Leading and trailing whitespace is allowed.

### Examples

```
Encode a steganographic encoder into a package
code-challenge,unicode,steganography
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65159/encode-a-steganographic-encoder-into-a-package

Simple predictive keyboard CG
code-golf
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76196/simple-predictive-keyboard-cg
```

### Scoring

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: I'm getting really sick of [tag:stack-exchange-api] challenges.

Comment: @Riker Uhm... thanks for your feedback? I really don't know why you would downvote for that reason but more power to you, I guess.

Comment: I didn't downvote for that. I downvoted because I think the question is boring. Also, would closed questions need to have the equal probability of being outputted?

Comment: Thank you for expressing concerns with the question even after disliking it.

Comment: While I don't feel as strongly about it as @Riker, there does seem to have be a *lot* of API-related challenges lately; so much so that [I managed to get myself blocked from using the API for ~21 hours](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120071/58974)!

Comment: I will admit I got this idea after seeing the sudden influx of API questions.

Comment: At this rate, we'll have to ask SE for an unthrottled "sanbox" API to work with on all these challenges! :D

Comment: Interestingly enough, this challenge will show up during testing, but once I answer it, it won't show up in testing anymore.

Comment: I suggest, to avoid hammering the API with multiple requests and having people hit the throttle trying to retrieve *all* unanswered that you add a minimum number of answers that we should work with that can be retrieved with a single API request, i.e. `<=100`.

Comment: I also suggest that translating the output to "human readable format" be removed from the question as it adds an unnecessary (in my opinion) extra complication to the challenge that not all languages will be able to handle while remaining competitive. I think there's a post on Meta that covers this, I'll see if I can dig it out.

Comment: Note your example list is now wrong as the Tetris challenge has been answered :D

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript + HTML, <s>271</s> <s>250</s> 232 bytes

*Apparantly you can use `Date`s as pseudo-random numbers. I stole this from [Shaggy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120196/48878).*

(Only uses about 4 of your quota)

```js
q=[]
g=f=>fetch('//api.stackexchange.com/questions/unanswered?site=codegolf&page='+f).then(r=>r.json().then(j=>(q=[...q,...j.items])^j.has_more?g(f+1):document.write(`<pre>${(q=q[new Date%q.length]).title}
${q.tags}
`+q.link)))
g(1)
```

It makes an array `q`, then calls `g(1)`, which fetches the first page of results and adds it to q. Then, if the request says it `has_more`, then it calls `g(f+1)`, which fetches the next page, until it reaches the end and writes out to the HTML document (Which will automatically unescape the response)

If we don't care about *all* of the unanswered questions, just the most recent 30 (Only uses 1 of your quota):

### JavaScript + HTML, <s>213</s> <s>196</s> 179 bytes

```js
fetch`//api.stackexchange.com/questions/unanswered?site=codegolf`.then(r=>r.json().then(j=>document.write(`<pre>${(j=j.items[new Date%j.items.length]).title}
${j.tags}
`+j.link)))
```

Comment: Sorry, @Artyer, I was so focused on working on my own answer, I never spotted that you'd beaten me to the punch by a few minutes. I'm happy to delete my answer, if you feel it's to similar to yours.

Comment: @Shaggy It's alright. I also wrote the second answer at the same time as you wrote your answer, so it's a happy coincidence that they ended up similar.

Comment: You could save a few byes by hardcoding in the number of pages that need to be fetched. Instead of `j.has_more?g(f+1)`, try `++f<5?g(f)`

Comment: You could also replace `q=q.concat(j.items)` with `q=[...q,...j.items]`. It looks like `Tags: ` is optional, so you can drop that too. And no need to `join` `q.tags`, it will be coerced into a string when being concatenated to a string. Finally, using a template literal for the final should save you a few bytes, too.

Comment: @Shaggy Unfortunately, I've met my quota. It resets in 425 seconds though.

Comment: After further consideration, I've decided to delete my answer. Your paging solution is now almost identical to the one I was working before I decided to ditch the paging in order to save multiple requests to the API.

Comment: **TIP:** To avoid being booted from the API when testing, grab a sample set of data and use it as I did in the second Snippet [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120071/58974)

Comment: Your code also returns answered questions: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/143220/simple-complexity was returned and that question has two answers.

Answer (score 6):

## Python + requests + json + random + html, <s>249</s> 239 bytes

```
import requests as r,json,random as R,html
j=R.choice(json.loads(r.get('http://api.stackexchange.com/questions/no-answers?site=codegolf').text)['items'])
print('\n'.join([html.unescape(j['title']),'Tags: '+', '.join(j['tags']),j['link']]))
```

Turned out longer than I'd like.

-10 bytes thanks to @totallyhuman by using `R.choice` rather than `R.shuffle` and taking the first element.

Comment: Can you save a few bytes by using `random.shuffle`?

Comment: ...Wait, or even better, `random.choice()`?

Comment: @totallyhuman Changing the inpurt name happens to actually make no difference in bytecount :P But thanks for `.choice()`!

Comment: You don't need the json library, use `r.get(url).json()` instead

Comment: This doesn't account for `has_more`. It only randomly chooses from the first 30.

Answer (score 0):

## Bash <strike>255</strike> 232 bytes

```
a="api.stackexchange.com/questions/";b="?site=codegolf";c=$(w3m $a"unanswered"$b"&filter=total"|tr -cd 0-9);w3m $a"no-answers"$b"&pagesize=1&page="$((RANDOM%c))|jq -r ".items[0]|.title,(.tags|join(\", \")),.link"|recode html..utf-8
```

Looks like a wrong results returns for totals for no-answers/unanswered. General idea - get total, than get random page with one item.

## Bash <strike>174</strike> 153 bytes

```
w3m api.stackexchange.com/questions/no-answers?site=codegolf|jq -r ".items[$RANDOM%(.items|length)]|.title,(.tags|join(\", \")),.link"|recode html..utf-8
```

It select one random question from last 30, not from all questions. Works from command line. Required <strike>curl</strike> w3m, jq and recode.

result:

```
Tips for golfing in Charcoal
code-golf, tips
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/117269/tips-for-golfing-in-charcoal
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to choose from all of them. But welcome to PPCG anyway!